# Which type of users has access to org limits?

Tags: permissions, limits

I would like to know how to be sure which type of users has permissions to see org limits, and how to manage it if it's possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As started in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.dev_force_com_system_overview_page.htm&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=5), users must have Customize Application. You just need to make your users non-system administrators. You can use a custom profile or any standard profile except System Administrator.